# Sort results from speech recognition

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, speech-recognition

I have implement the new Speech Recognition in my project. If tapping on record button the recognition do it work and put my spoken words in **myLabel**. What I'm looking for is, to separate the spoken results, for example: start to speak and sort the words in separate table cells in one step, without start and stop the AVEngine every time.
Thankful for all approaches.

Comment: What are asking for? Sort the words in the recognition result into a tableview?

Comment: while speaking to sort partial parts of the recognition into a tableview.

Comment: basically if the recognition ends with tapping on respective button, I can assign the entire spoken text to an label or text field, but what I want is, to assign parts of already spoken text to tableview while speaking. I hope express my self understandable